# AngularJS catch-all route?

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm working on a file editing application in AngularJS. My urls look like this:

> #/fileName.md

or

> #/folder/fileName.md

or

> #/folder/nested-folder/another-folder/itgoesonforever/filename.MD

I don't want to have to do a route for every single depth and it could be ~15 routes deep. Are there any ways to have conditional routes? Crudely:

```
/:fileorfolder?/:fileorfolder?/:fileorfolder?/:fileorfolder?
```

Comment: Sorry? Can you explain?

Comment: I've never messed with Angular's routing, but I have read of the Angular UI project's router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router Does that address your needs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the best you can do with Angular is `*`, which is new as of  [v1.1.5 of $routeProvider](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24routeProvider):

> `path` can contain named groups starting with a star (`*name`). All characters are eagerly stored in `$routeParams` under the given name when the route matches.
>   For example, routes like `/color/:color/largecode/*largecode/edit` will match `/color/brown/largecode/code/with/slashes/edit` and extract:
>     - `color: brown`
>     - `largecode: code/with/slashes`

You'd have to parse the `largecode` param yourself though.

Comment: Wow, exactly what I wanted. I don't even have to do any weird joining after the fact as its all passed as a single param. Thanks a ton!

Comment: This has now been changed to `:name*` in more recent versions of angular.

Answer (score 6):

I think I got it! The trick is to set the template to a simple , then modify the scope to include the dynamic path to your template.

So now I can place a file at `/foo/bar/baz.html` and see the template rendered by going to `server.com/foo/bar/baz`.

```
// Routes
app.config( function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    // Home
    .when( '/', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })

    // Catch All
    .when( '/:templatePath*', {
        template: '<ng-include src="templatePath"></ng-include>',
        controller: 'CatchAllCtrl'
    })

});

// Catch All Controller
app.controller("CatchAllCtrl", function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.templatePath = $routeParams.templatePath + '.html';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could look at using the routeProvider#otherwise functionality

```
  $routeProvider
    .otherwise({controller: 'FileEditor',...});
```

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider)

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I don't get the routeParams then, which buggers up my app.