# How to add relatives routes for an AngularJs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have been following the concept of componentalization, and is an advocate of it, but kind of looking for a solution for a normal scenario below. It could be that my approach is wrong and must be changed, or something I am unaware of.  I have been looking everywhere and trying out many things, but havent seen a success. It must be something I missed out.

I want to add a componenent with internal routing. Basically, the idea is this component can exist on any page, but uses a relative route from its parent to be in a particular state.

The requirement is that it can exist in different tabs which has states and it has to be a directive.

Can someone help me out with this concept or point me in the right direction? Would want to implement it in **AngularJS 1.4**

**Edited**

The below image depicts the scenario. Can we place the register component/directive in any tab, be it dashboard or tab2 or tab3. 
[image: When the register directive component is in dashboard]
[image: When the register directive component is in tab3]

We also have states in the Register component( I understand that states work in when config runs), but those are to be handled  in the component code, but should stay independent of the parent route, like a standalone component.

eg: if component ABC is in page1, the route should be page1/ABC/step1
if later we decide to move it to another page, the route should be page3/ABC/step1 and this has to be done without adding the routes "page.ABC.step1" and "page.ABC.step2"

**So the idea is to move around the directive without changing route configs.**

I hope I have conveyed the idea properly. If you need more do let me know.

Comment: Can you provide a pseudo example? Not really clear what `internal routes` means

Comment: @charlietfl I have added more details with pictures.

Comment: @Tedscape, Probably what you refer as internal routing relates to the dynamic routing.. 

You could achieve that with routing params with * wildcard.  It's known as catch-all route parameter.

See more in these links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681116/angularjs-dynamic-routing

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576892/angularjs-catch-all-route